# jQuery Mobile Styling DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

***Using JQM 1.3***

In my markup inside content I have:

```
<div class="simpleCart_items" ></div>
```

This div will be filled using content from a javascript file. Actually it will output items that were added to a shopping cart list.

Also there is this link "remove" that it is also generated next to each of the items in the list. I cant waste the oportunity to style this link with a nice JQM mini button that you can show with this code:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="Remove" data-iconpos="notext">Delete</a>
```

Inside the javascript I found the line that is in charge of generating this remove link.

```
remove: function (item, column) {
                    return "<a href='javascript:;' class='" + namespace + "_remove'>" + (column.text || "X") + "</a>";
            }
```

On firebug this line will output just like this:

```
<div class="item-remove">
<a class="simpleCart_remove" href="javascript:;">Remove</a>
</div>
```

As a total newbie to the events and DOM I thought "hey, why dont you add this data-role atributes to this javascript line ?" You guys know that it wont work just like that.

I have read that this link tag is not taking into account by JQM styles when the page loads for wherever reason.

After trying everything, I give up doing it by my self. If you guys come out with an script, please tell me exactly where to place it this might somehow affects the results.

Answer (score 0):

In jQM after you add a button programmatically you need to call `refresh` method to let jQM enhance its markup.

```
$("<a href='#' data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' data-inline='true' class='simpleCart_remove'>Remove</a>")
    .appendTo("div.simpleCart_items")
    .buttonMarkup('refresh');
```

Here is working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/GBYBA/)**

In the jsfiddle example I changed `<a>` to `<button>` (BTW it's more succinct) to play nicely with a listview and bind a `click` event to remove items.

Comment: @user2109326 Did you look at jsFiddle I provided in the answer? You need to use proper jQM events, not just put a bunch of code in a script tag somewhere, which I guess you did.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Its exactly what I did, took your code and paste it. I looked over the js file, and it does exactly what I needed. But I am this newbie to events that even what such a good demonstration I cant make it work for my project. Perhaps one day, some one will read this tread and find it usefull and inspiring. I feel so lame to waste your expert answer. Best wishes for you.

Comment: Could I take the class .simpleCart_remove and using only css3, add the missing clases and data atributes to the elements that use this class ?